# How to deal with questions that are more recomendations?

Tags: support, asking-questions

One of the biggest problems with the Magento community is that i'm always being asked by clients about *"what X plugin could you recommend"* and *"what are your thoughts on Y plugin"*  Yet I have absolutely no idea.

Also, I can't actually review the extensions code or the extension without purchasing it, and I am unable to write my own extensions because most companies don't want to pay a developer to write one.

So, I would like to ask the community of people for their recommendations of good (paid or otherwise) extensions.  I've seen 5 star rated extensions from vendors such as Magestore (who are one of the worst developers I have ever had the displeasure of fixing their rubbish).

Since this is a more technical Q&A, how can these types of questions be structured or are they totally forbidden (since it's arguably opinion based)?

Comment: ["Find an extension that..."](http://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you are asking is one of the reasons why we had to rule out Stack as a permanent replacement or the Magento forums.

With the launch of the new forums you will notice that we have an Extension category with a
["Find an extension that..."](http://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension) subforum which would probably be a good home for questions such as yours.